# Formula for finding how much base to add to buffer to obtain a desired pH

Tags: titration

Given: molarity and volume of the weak acid, molarity of the strong base, desired $\ce{pH}$, $K_{a}$ of the acid. I tried coming up with a formula to solve for the amount of base to add in order to reach the $\ce{pH}$.
$$\ce{HA + OH- -> H2O + A-}$$

After addition of $\ce{OH-}$:

$n_{\ce{HA}}=M_{\ce{HA}}V_{\ce{HA}} - M_{\ce{OH-}}V_{\ce{OH-}}$

$n_{\ce{OH-}}=M_{\ce{OH-}}V_{\ce{OH-}} - M_{\ce{OH-}}V_{\ce{OH-}} = 0$ mol

$n_{\ce{A-}}=0 + M_{\ce{OH-}}V_{\ce{OH}} = M_{\ce{OH-}}V_{\ce{OH-}}$

$$\ce{HA + H2O <=> H3O+ + A-}$$
Using an ICE table, the concentrations at equilibrium become:

$[\ce{H3O+}]=10^{-\ce{pH}}$ (given the desired $\ce{pH}$)

$\ce{[HA]}=\frac{n_{\ce{HA}}}{V_{soln}}=\frac{M_{\ce{HA}}V_{\ce{HA}} - M_{\ce{OH-}}V_{\ce{OH-}}}{V_{\ce{HA}} + V_{\ce{OH-}}}-[\ce{H3O+}]=\frac{M_{\ce{HA}}V_{\ce{HA}} - M_{\ce{OH-}}V_{\ce{OH-}}}{V_{\ce{HA}} + V_{\ce{OH-}}}-10^{-\ce{pH}}$

$[\ce{A-}]=\frac{n_{\ce{A-}}}{V_{soln}}=\frac{M_{\ce{OH-}}V_{\ce{OH-}}}{V_{\ce{HA}} + V_{\ce{OH-}}}+[\ce{H3O+}] = \frac{M_{\ce{OH-}}V_{\ce{OH-}}}{V_{\ce{HA}} + V_{\ce{OH-}}} + 10^{-\ce{pH}}$

Writing a $K_{a}$ expression gives:

$$K_{a}=\frac{\ce{[H3O+][A-]}}{\ce{[HA]}}=\frac{10^{-\ce{pH}}\left(\frac{M_{\ce{OH-}}V_{\ce{OH-}}}{V_{\ce{HA}} + V_{\ce{OH-}}} + 10^{-\ce{pH}}\right)}{\frac{M_{\ce{HA}}V_{\ce{HA}} - M_{\ce{OH-}}V_{\ce{OH-}}}{V_{\ce{HA}} + V_{\ce{OH-}}}-10^{-\ce{pH}}}$$
I tried rewriting this to solve for $V_{\ce{OH-}}$ and got:

$$V_{\ce{OH-}} = \frac{ V_{\ce{HA}}(10^{-2\ce{pH}} - K_{a}M_{\ce{HA}}) }{ -10^{-\ce{pH}}(-10^{-{\ce{pH}}}+M_{\ce{OH-}}) -K_{\mathrm{a}}M_{\ce{OH-}} }$$

Is this a valid formula? Could this be used to determine how much strong base to add to a buffer in order to reach a desired $\ce{pH}$? Is there an easier way to write this? Is it useful at all? Thanks.